# How do you load KitchenSink in Sencha Architect?

Tags: sencha-architect

Sencha Architect allows you to import projects easily. However, the program requires the project to be archived as .xds or .xda. How do I do that for the default projects like KitchenSink, Kiva, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thiem is correct, the well know kitchen sink demo is not an architect project so it can not be imported. However there are several demo projects both for Ext.js and Touch. You can grab them at Sencha Architect repository on [Github](https://github.com/SenchaArchitect). More information on Example Projects can be found in the [Sencha Architect](https://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/tutorials/example_projects.html) documentation.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Kitchen Sink and Kiva are just normal Sencha Touch projects. If they are not developed with Sencha Architect (and later packaged in a .xds or .xda file), there's no way to open them in Sencha Architect since it does not understand how to "interpret" your pure Sencha Touch code into Sencha Architect component and configs.