# How to use EXTJS Kitchen Sink and other Demo Applications while working with Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I was going thru examples provided on Sencha portal such as http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/

One such example is LiveSearchGrid http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/classic/grid/live-search-grid.js

We are using Sencha Architect in our application. If I want to use LiveSearchGrid in my class, then how would I use it? I do not see any options to add custom components. To add, we can install extensions etc but in the current context where I am more inclined to use to use ready to use examples provided by Sencha Team, I am not sure, how can i add it using Sencha Architect.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at this thread: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764897/how-do-you-load-kitchensink-in-sencha-architect

Comment: @AbdulRehmanYawarKhan - Yes, I understand that part. If the component is not exported as (.xda or xdc ) then we cant open it in sencha architect. Agreed. My Question is, If I want to use a custom component in my application, then after loading the component in application, how can I add it to the items array in panel (using xtype) as I do not see any option in Sencha Architect to do that

Comment: Reference the .js file in your index.html and add requires config (pointing to the .js file) on Application level in Architect. Then you can use it in code, like this Ext.<foldername>.LibraryName.<requiredFunction>
FolderName: is location of where you dropped the file